# Why does MouseDown event have a 6 second delay in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mousedown

Current working code with mouse:

```
Private Sub FilterMouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnFilterUp.MouseDown
    'Do something
End Sub
```

I would like to work with a touch screen now, but the touch driver doesn't allow a finger touching and holding the button to register as a MouseDown until 6 seconds later.  This is too long of a delay for my application and I can't figure out how to disable this touch issue.

As a work around, I would like to have the ability to register a touch event in the vb code.  I was thinking it would look something like this:

```
Private Sub FilterMouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TouchEventArgs) Handles btnFilterUp.TouchDown
    'Do something
End Sub
```

Can this be done with Visual Studio 2013 Express?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?  Do I need to add a touch library or something?

Comment: Reworded my question.  Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right, it sounds like the touch screen device driver doesn't register touches until after you hold your finger on the screen for more than 6 seconds?

Comment: Try clicking with an actual mouse and compare the difference when using your finger to touch the screen. How long does it take for the mouse click to register?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b: An actual mouse registers a MouseDown event immediately.  A finger touch (and hold) takes 6 seconds until the MouseDown event registers.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini: The touch screen driver right-click enable has been unchecked, but it still seems to act as though it's looking for a right-click event when a touch is held down on a button.  Touching a button with a finger and letting go registers a click event in the vb code just fine.  I want the user to press and hold the button (MouseDown event in vb) for a different action than when they just touch and let go of the button (click event in vb).

Comment: I see. I think you're running into the limitations of the driver itself. If the touch driver won't report a MouseDown event right away, there's nothing you can do to force it to work. You may have to come up with a different UX interaction.

Comment: @ Nate Barbettini.  I thnk you are right.  A different UX interaction may be the next step if my solution is not acceptable to the user.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini: You can handle whatever action that you want in the MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove events. During mousedown and on mouseup, get the time it took for the user to lift his/her finger. Then if for example, you want Action A to be performed if the the user lifted his/her finger on or before 6 seconds and you want Action B to be performed when the user lifted his/her finger 6 seconds and over. You must also consider the fact that the user might move his/her finger away from the button while it is still pressed. So you might want to take a different action there.

Comment: This was not possible because the MouseDown would not happen until after a 6 second delay.  If a touch is release before 6 seconds, only a MouseClick would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally stumbled on a fix. It's not pretty, but I think it will do the job: 
1.  Open up the Control Panel and open up the Pen and Touch Settings. 
2.  On the Touch tab, click on the Press and hold touch action and then click on Settings… 
3.  Check the “Enable press and hold for right-clicking” box, change the Speed all the way to Short, and change the Duration all the way to Short. 
4.  Uncheck the “Enable press and hold for right-clicking” box, and click OK.  Then click Apply and OK.

After this change, the delay should be 1 second instead of 6.